# Rails: Is it possible to group 'render' for multiple methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, render

Is it possible to group the *render* method for multiple methods?

Here is my case: Many methods of my controller share the same view. Only data changes (the data will be used to select the default option of a *select* HTML field). P.S.: I know there is a better way to do that (like using *show* method,) but the purpose is to have sexier URL (see below).

```
def index
end

def flower
    @object = flower
    render 'index'
end

def car
    @object = car
    render 'index'
end

... (other objects)
```

This is to be able to use *match* in the **routes.rb** file:

```
match 'flower', :to => 'objects#flower'
match 'car', :to => 'objects#car'
...
```

So, in order to Not Repeat Myself, can I group the same *render* for many methods?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `after_filter`:

```
after_filter :render_index

def render_index
   render 'index'
end
```

Comment: Thanks Talgat, but not all my methods use the same render file. So I get _multiple render_ error when I specify the render view in the method (**create** for example.)

Comment: You can use :only attribute, `after_filter :render_index, :only => [:create, :some_action]` Look here for more details http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

Comment: Unfortunately, it ended with **Template is missing** error: _Missing template objects/flower, application/flower with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}._ !

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like:

```
get ':source', :to => 'objects#index', constraints: {source: /\A(flower|car|etc)\z/}

def index
  @object = send(params[:source]) if params[:source].present?
end
```

It'll be very important to constrain your list of sources so as to not allow execution of arbitrary methods, but this would let you use a single route and single action easily.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I love the solution you suggested, but applying it returns a _500 Internal Server Error: undefined method `flower' for #<ObjectsController:0x007ff91d0a3098>_!! Any idea?

Comment: Using _rake routes_ returns: GET /:object(.:format) object#index {:object=>/(flower|car|cat)/}